# 'Undefined' result in Javascript testing

Tags: javascript, object, testing, undefined

I am creating a Kata on Codewars. Its objective is to make a Player with certain attributes and values.
This is the complete working solution,

```
function Player(name, position, age, dribbling, pass, shoot) {
 this.name = name;
 this.position = position;
 this.age = age;
 this.dribbling = dribbling;
 this.pass = pass;
 this.shoot = shoot;
} 

var myPlayer = new Player('Player', 'Right Winger', 25, 75, 90, 65);
```

And this is the Test Cases I have to provide to validate the complete working solution in order to publish the Kata,

```
describe('Player class', function () {
  it('should create a Player', function (){
    var myPlayer = new Player()
      Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.name, 'Player')
      Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.position, 'Right Winger')
      Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.age, 25)
      Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.dribbling, 75)
      Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.pass, 90)
      Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.shoot, 65)
    })
})`
```

And this is the result I get when I run the 'Validate Solution' button,

```
Player class
should create a Player
Expected: Player, instead got: undefined
Expected: Right Winger, instead got: undefined
Expected: 25, instead got: undefined
Expected: 75, instead got: undefined
Expected: 90, instead got: undefined
Expected: 65, instead got: undefined

0 Passed
6 Failed
0 Errors
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: because when you call `new Player()` you pass all parameter _undefined_

Comment: There's nothing wrong. You've got result of assertions against your fed code. Check the messages to know how to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Here you didn't pass anything

```
var myPlayer = new Player()
```

that's why every property of `myPlayer` is `undefined`

instead try this

```
var myPlayer = new Player('Player', 'Right Winger', 25, 75, 90, 65);
Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.name, 'Player');
Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.position, 'Right Winger');
Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.age, 25);
Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.dribbling, 75);
Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.pass, 90);
Test.assertEquals(myPlayer.shoot, 65);
```

Comment: Now it works, my bad I didn't notice this important feature. The devil is in the details!

Comment: glad this helped you :)